# Would a Singleton be suitable in this case?

Tags: java, static, singleton

Imagine I have a class called `FileManager`. This class handles creating files and retrieving data from these files, along with loading and saving data from these files. This class will only ever need to have one instance. Should I use a Singleton to keep it as one instance (since that is all that is required) or should I just create a new instance each time?

I ask that you support your answer with a solid reason with facts.

EDIT: Here is an example using the Singleton. As an additional question, should this use eager or lazy instantiation? What would be the advantage to either and which is more acceptable in this case *and* in general?

```
public class FileManager {

private static FileManager instance;
private static File kitFile = null;
private static File langFile = null;

private static FileConfiguration langData = null;
private static FileConfiguration kitData = null;

public static FileManager getInstance() {
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new FileManager();
    if(kitFile == null)
        kitFile = new File(Kits.getInstance().getDataFolder(), "Kits.yml");
    if(kitData == null)
        kitData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(kitFile);
    if(langFile == null)
        langFile = new File(Kits.getInstance().getDataFolder(), "/lang/"+Kits.getInstance().getConfig().getString("lang"));
    if(langData == null)
        langData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(langFile);
    return instance;
}
```

The code goes on to have methods which create the files, save data to these files, and load data from these files. These methods are only called in one class. The code, then, goes on to have getters which are used throughout various classes.

Comment: Does it carry stateful information?  If not, then I'd consider just making the methods `static` (or a static utility class). If it does, is that state information sharable across multiple access points (i.e. multiple threads/classes)?  If not, then you should avoid using a singleton. Based on your limited description, I'd be leaning towards a utility class, realistically, all the information that the class needs can be passed to it via parameters to the methods - but that's me

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [this blog](https://dzone.com/articles/java-singletons-using-enum) for a better singleton implementation. I'd also suggestion that it doesn't make sense for the properties to be `static`

Comment: You don’t want a singleton. They are actually quite rare.  The only time I can remember creating one is for a DB connection pool where it shared connections across threads.

Comment: This should not be a singleton, because you won't be able to create another instance using a different `Kits`. And `Kits` (whatever that is) should not be a singleton either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its a good idea to implement a public getInstance method here. Is that a better way to implement some methods called "saveXXFile", "readXXFile" in this class? In that way, you can also avoid multithreading errors which may occur in your code.

In another word, if I write this, I may encapsulate some methods called "saveXXFile", "readXXFile" in this class rather than exposing the file instances to the class users.